# How to I configure open_basedir parameter under my Centos VPS?

Tags: centos, vps

The parameter can be seen here

http://wordswithfriends.net/test.php

```
open_basedir    /var/www/vhosts/wor.wordswithfriends.net/wordswithfriends.net/:/tmp
```

I'm trying to add PHP pear directories

/var/www/vhosts/wor.wordswithfriends.net/conf is as follows

```
-rw-r-----  1 root apache   6461 Jan 25 08:56 12959674170.16899500_httpd.include
-rw-r-----  1 root apache   6461 Jan 31 06:52 12960111810.31860800_httpd.include
-rw-r-----  1 root apache   6532 Jan 31 06:55 12964785250.54523600_httpd.include
-rw-r-----  1 root apache   6532 Jan 31 07:01 12964788880.47252600_httpd.include
-rw-r-----  1 root apache   6532 Jan 31 15:54 12965108850.92819600_httpd.include
-rw-r-----  1 root apache   6652 Jan 31 21:32 12965206700.32285200_httpd.include
```

Currently configured as follows

```
grep base 12965206700.32285200_httpd.include
php_admin_value open_basedir /var/www/vhosts/wor.wordswithfriends.net/httpdocs/:/tmp/:/usr/share/pear/:/local/PEAR/
php_admin_value open_basedir /var/www/vhosts/wor.wordswithfriends.net/httpdocs/:/tmp/:/usr/share/pear/:/local/PEAR/
php_admin_value open_basedir /var/www/vhosts/wor.wordswithfriends.net/httpdocs/:/tmp/:/usr/share/pear/:/local/PEAR/
php_admin_value open_basedir /var/www/vhosts/wor.wordswithfriends.net/httpdocs/:/tmp/:/usr/share/pear/:/local/PEAR/
```

Configured vhost.conf as follows

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/wor.wordswithfriends.net/wordswithfriends.net>
<IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
php_admin_flag engine on
php_admin_flag safe_mode off
php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/vhosts/wor.wordswithfriends.net:/tmp:/usr/share/pear/local/PEAR"
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_admin_flag engine on
php_admin_flag safe_mode off
php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/vhosts/wor.wordswithfriends.net:/tmp:/usr/share/pear:/local/PEAR"
</IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Restarted apache and the parameter is still the same. I'm not sure why my pear directories are not showing up.  I'm using Plesk. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You have to recompile Plesk with the changes. You can do this using

> /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/websrvmng -v -a

on the command line, as root

Answer (score 0):

Make a PHP file with this in it:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

View the file in the browser. It will tell you the location of the php.ini it's using.
Modify the php.ini's value for open_basedir and restart Apache.